# SvelteKit: Using @sveltejs/adapter-node throwing error

Tags: node.js, svelte, sveltekit

adopter-node throwing error while building the sveltekit app for production.

I made a configuration changes (instead of @sveltejs/adapter-auto, I used '@sveltejs/adapter-node') in svelte.config.js file. While making the production build by executing "npm run build", we are getting below error.

> Using @sveltejs/adapter-node
> builder.writePrerendered is not a function

Comment: Hey, when you ask a question in StackOverflow, you want to try to provide a small reproducible code so that people can reproduce the problem

Comment: For making production builds in SvelteKit we have to choose one of the adapters such as Netlify / Vercel / Node. So I chose Node here.

Comment: This issue was known by the svelte devs here: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/4224

Try updating to the latest version of sveltekit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node adapter issue got resolved after I updated my svelteKit version as suggested in this below thread
[Adapter-Node](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/4224)